# Unable to match start-of-line using egrep

Tags: regex, egrep

I've the following command that works good on my macOS;

```
git branch | egrep -v --regex "$REGEX_PATTERN" | xargs git branch -D
```

where the `REGEX_PATTERN=(develop|master|release|)`.

When I change my regex into `REGEX_PATTERN=^(develop|master|release|)` to eliminate potentially embedded branch names, I can't get it working. So, I probably misuse the `egrep` but can't figure out how. That would be great if someone can point what might be the issue?

PS: I have another regex pattern that contains the very same `^` character which is passed over a `find` command and that works as expected.